# Selected Combox na javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Boa noite pessoal, preciso de uma ajuda, é simples mas estou enrolado.
Tenho essa combo dentro de uma MODAL, ocorre que os campos desta modal eu populo tudo por javascript/Json buscando os dados de um banco de dados.

MODAL

```
<!-- Grid column -->
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">                                     
   <div class="md-form form-sm">
      <select class="mdb-select colorful-select dropdown-primary" searchable="Busca por nível.." id="frmnivelacesso">
         <option value="1"> Master</option>
         <option value="2"> Secretária/Recepcionista</option>
         <option value="3"> Cirurgião Dentista</option>
      </select>
      <label for="form8" class="">Nivel de acesso</label>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- Grid column -->
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#ModalUsuarioEdit").on('shown.bs.modal', function(){

        var id = $('#ModalUsuarioEdit').data('id'); 
        $.post('estrutura/usuario.php',{acao:'select',id:id},function(r) { 
               var ev = jQuery.parseJSON(r);           
               if (ev.success) {


                    document.getElementById('frm-imgname').src = 'arquivos/images/' + ev.foto;
                    var nomecompleto = ev.nome + ' ' + ev.sobrenome;
                    $("#frm-username").text(nomecompleto);

                    $("#frmnome").val(ev.nome);  
                    $("#frmsobrenome").val(ev.sobrenome); 
                    $("#frmdtnascimento").val(ev.nascimento); 
                    $("#frmcargo").val(ev.cargo); 
                    $("#frmemail").val(ev.email); 
                    $("#frmtelefone").val(ev.telefone); 
                    $("#frmcro").val(ev.cro); 
                    $("#frmusuario").val(ev.usuario); 
                    $("#frmsenha").val(ev.senha); 

                    $("#frmnivelacesso").val(ev.nivel); // nesse ponto não sei como fazer com que a option da combo fique seleciona 

                    $("#frmnome").focus();
                    $("#frmsobrenome").focus();
                    $("#frmdtnascimento").focus();
                    $("#frmcargo").focus();
                    $("#frmemail").focus();
                    $("#frmtelefone").focus();
                    $("#frmcro").focus();
                    $("#frmusuario").focus();
                    $("#frmsenha").focus();
                    $("#btnfechar").focus();

               }         
        });
```

Comment: Nâo ficou claro qual sua dúvida.

Comment: Tá, mas qual é a duvida?

Comment: Desculpa, esqueci de informar, conforme retorno da base quero deixar o parametro "selected" ativo para o valor correspondente. ex: ev.nivel = 1 então  <option value="1" selected> Master</option>.

Answer (score 1):

Você seleciona a `option` pelo `value` (`.val()`), selecionando o `select` pelo `id`, desta forma:

```
$("#frmnivelacesso").val(ev.nivel);
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
var ev = { nivel: 2 }
$("#frmnivelacesso").val(ev.nivel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Grid column -->
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">                                     
   <div class="md-form form-sm">
      <select class="mdb-select colorful-select dropdown-primary" searchable="Busca por nível.." id="frmnivelacesso">
         <option value="1"> Master</option>
         <option value="2"> Secretária/Recepcionista</option>
         <option value="3"> Cirurgião Dentista</option>
      </select>
      <label for="form8" class="">Nivel de acesso</label>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- Grid column -->
```

Ou usando o método `.prop()`:

```js
var ev = { nivel: 3 }
$("#frmnivelacesso option[value='"+ev.nivel+"']").prop("selected", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Grid column -->
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">                                     
   <div class="md-form form-sm">
      <select class="mdb-select colorful-select dropdown-primary" searchable="Busca por nível.." id="frmnivelacesso">
         <option value="1"> Master</option>
         <option value="2"> Secretária/Recepcionista</option>
         <option value="3"> Cirurgião Dentista</option>
      </select>
      <label for="form8" class="">Nivel de acesso</label>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- Grid column -->
```

Comment: Isso foi o que fiz, mas em tela a combo não deixou o valor selecionado, olhe no meu código na pergunta, esta desta forma, o valor esta sendo passado para a combo, porem preciso que esse valor fique selecionado.

Comment: Adicionei na resposta outro método. Se não funcionar nenhum dos dois (pelo que já disse, o primeiro não funcionou), aí temos que ver o que pode ser, porque não é normal, deveria funcionar

Comment: Não funciona, acho que deve ser algo na modal, vou revisar, deixei fixo o valor para teste e não rolou.. var teste = 2;
     $("#frm34 option[value='"+teste+"']").prop("selected", true);

Comment: Só o select que não funciona? Os outros campos estão recebendo valor? Estou testando aqui no servidor.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui, funciona normal: http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/teste.php

Comment: Se o código `$("#frmnome").val(ev.nome);`, por exemplo, está funcionando, então o `$("#frmnivelacesso").val(ev.nivel);` tb deveria funcionar, já que ambos estão no mesmo bloco.